# Setting state with Pinia using Options API

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pinia

I have this store defined in the options API:

```
import { defineStore } from "pinia";
import AxiosBeerOffice from "@/services/axiosBeerOffice";

const uri = {
  getNavbarItems: "/navbarItems",
};

export const useNavbarStore = defineStore({
  id: "navbar",
  state: () => ({
    navbarItems: [],
  }),
  actions: {
    getNavbarItems: async () => {
      const response = await AxiosBeerOffice.get(uri.getNavbarItems, true);
      const { data } = response;
      this.navbarItems = data;
    },
  },
});
```

The problem is when I call the `getNavbarItems` actions, the line that set the value to `navbarItems` throws me this error:

[image]

I really don't understand what is going on so any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arrow functions doesn’t have their own bindings to `this` which explains the error with `this.navbarItems`. Try the below instead:

```
  actions: {
    async getNavbarItems() {
      // …
    },
  },
```

Based on https://github.com/vuejs/pinia/discussions/1267.
Also see examples from https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/actions.html